# Ordering column values when concatenating to a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to do a simple kind of a sort for column values
when concatenating 2 or more columns to a single column in a select (there seems to be few related question but not quite what I want and having far too complicated answers)?

Consider the following scenario:

Having a table like:

```
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    name varchar,
    name2 varchar
);
```

with data:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
    ('N1', 'N2')
   ,('N2', 'N1')
;
```

Selecting like:

```
SELECT (name||name2) AS id, * from t1;
```

results into:

```
   id  | name | name2      
------+------+-------  
  N1N2 | N1   | N2    
  N2N1 | N2   | N1
```

I would like to have the latter row **also** to be `N1N2` instead of `N2N1`. So what I am after is something like:

```
SELECT (concat(sort(name,name2))) AS id, * from t1 ;
```

should result into:

```
   id  | name | name2      
------+------+-------  
  N1N2 | N1   | N2    
  N1N2 | N2   | N1
```

so if the SET of column values of `name` & `name2` is the same then the `id` is the same.

**NOTE**: I realize that this would be possible to achieve by creating a function/procedure but I want to know if there is a more *Postgres standard way* to do it. Meaning that I would like to avoid installing any extensions or so but not so that it should work also in Oracle or MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to decide with a `CASE` clause:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5a85fed68bc57f1853928764ac8152f5)

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN name <= name2 THEN name || name2 
        ELSE name2 || name 
    END as id,
    name,
    name2
FROM t1
```

Result:

```
id     name    name2
N1N2   N1      N2
N1N2   N2      N1
```

---

If you would have more columns a more advanced sorting mechanism could be: Aggregating the columns into a column (aggregate them into an array and `unnest` all elements into one common column). This column can be sorted and aggregated into your `id` column:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9ab429342a7abc9218948ea926c099c8)

```
SELECT 
    array_to_string(array_agg(all_columns ORDER BY all_columns), '') as ids,
    name, name2, name3, name4
FROM (
    SELECT 
        unnest(ARRAY[name, name2, name3, name4]) as all_columns,
        name, name2, name3, name4
    FROM t2
) s
GROUP BY name, name2, name3, name4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (least(name,name2)||greatest(name,name2)) AS id, *
FROM t1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: Had a hard time to choose the accepted answer. S-Man did a little bit more work so I ended up to S-man's aswer. Thanks!